# Terraform error - Error update server is not set

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform v0.14.7 I'm creating a cname record set, but when I put the command `terraform apply`, I got this message error:

> Error: update server is not set

In the Azure plataform in the "DNS ZONES" I have already created a zone called: `tech.com.br`:

```
provider "azurerm" {
features {}
}

resource "dns_cname_record" "foo" {
  zone = "tech.com.br."
  name = "foo"
  cname = "info.tech.com.br."
  ttl = 3600
}
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a DNS zone in the Azure platform, you can manage DNS CNAME Records within Azure DNS by using resource [azurerm_dns_cname_record](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/dns_cname_record) instead of `resource "dns_cname_record"`. Also, we don't need to provide the zone name with the dot `.` suffix.

Change your code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "foo" {
  zone_name = "tech.com.br"
  name = "foo"
  record = "info.tech.com.br"
  ttl = 3600
  resource_group_name = "YourDNSZoneRG"
}
```